# Getting static file not found that referenced by the handler GCP AppEngine

Tags: reactjs, google-app-engine, google-cloud-platform

For each and every deploying our reactjs app on app engine, blank screen is displayed and We are receiving Static file referenced by handler not found: index.html as an error in the logs and after clearing the cache from browser side is resolving the above issue. Earlier we did not face this issue. Please refer the app.yaml file below

```
runtime: nodejs10

env_variables:
  REACT_APP_ENV: "develope"
# service: ui
handlers:
  - url: /static
    static_dir: build/static
  - url: /.*
    secure: always
    script: auto
```

Comment: You didn't defined a runtime. Is it  normal?

Comment: @guillaumeblaquiere I have updated the app.yaml file. My bad missed it

Answer (score 0):

You have to mention where is your index.html. On a full static react app, I have this app.yaml description

```
runtime: nodejs10

handlers:
  - url: /
    static_files: build/index.html
    upload: build/index.html

  - url: /
    static_dir: build
```

I haven't backend. I don't know if you have one. Provide more precision on your service, I could help you to customize the deployment.

Comment: We tried the above app.yaml description, the issue didn't fixed. We are having Reactjs App front end only, API's are hosted separately

Comment: I don't know exactly your project architecture. Add more detail on the build folder content if you want more help!